# iOs 6 return from UIViewController in landscape to portrait

Tags: ios6, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

So I have an application with navigation controller, the last one viewcontoller can be rotated to any orientation. And the others must be in portrait only. So I have troubles when we rotate the last viewController in landscape and then pressing back button on navigation controller. We go to previous one and see that layout are broken. 
 I thought the only way is to use something like this:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"setOrientation:") withObject:(id)UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]
```

(I know it's a hack and it would be preferred to avoid such things)
But wherever I tried it - it caused me with different layout problems. The usual methods like:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
```

and so on for handle orientation are useless in this situation. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem for parent of those viewControllers who must be in portrait:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
 return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
 return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:YES];
}
```

For rotation viewController:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
 return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

For Navigation Controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

BOOL result = self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;

 return result;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

NSUInteger result = self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;

return result;
}
```

And added this to AppDelegate:

```
- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {

UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
if ([navigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[RotationViewController  class]])
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
else
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```